# how to implement in IOS two view controller via 'tabbed' for iPhone, and 'split' for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

How would one implement in IOS a view controller layout for an application that two key (equal) ways at highlighting data, such that for:

a) iphone - use of tabbed approach (so can select one of these views), but for

b) iPad - show two views on screen split down the middle vertically

Is there a way to do this so the framework will do this for me?  Or do I need to programmatically put in some If/Then's to manually load/show the controllers depending on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to 'do it yourself' effectively, but can use the IOS Custom Container View Controller support:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html